# creating a space before a variable including htmlencode str_repeat

Tags: php, html-encode

I have a variable given to me by my cms
    
I want to add one space before that but have tried many things lol and all dont work, below is what I have tried so far.

```
<?php echo str_repeat('', 1) htmlencode('$postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode']) ?>

<?php echo htmlencode('&nbsp$postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode']) ?>

<?php echo htmlencode('. $postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode'].) ?>

<?php echo '&nbsp''htmlencode('$postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode'])' ?>

<?php echo htmlencode('&nbsp''$postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode']) ?>
```

How can I minipulate 
    
where as the variable gives me one blank space prior to the variable content.

cheers for any input

emma

Comment: all your examples have problems with too many or little `'`

Comment: please consult [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) about basic string-concatanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These ones should work

```
echo ' '.htmlencode($postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode']);
```

or

```
echo '&nbsp;'.htmlencode($postcode_coveringsRecord['postcode']);
```

Comment: thank you that does work but is it possible to have it also use the htmlencode on the variable, as I am told by those that created the cms that  htmlencode offers a little protection.

Comment: thank you very much, i see what i had done wrong i was missing the . in the echo ' '.htmlen , now everythng works. thanks again ok. cheers

Comment: I am glad I could help!
You would do me a favor in return if you upvote and accept the answer ;-)

Comment: FWIW, you should use `echo ' ', ...` instead of an unnecessarily costly string concatenation.